# Is there a tool for identifying outdated/inconsistent JavaDoc comments?

Tags: java, ide

I'm looking for a tool (or IDE feature) that can point out incorrect JavaDoc comments. That is, comments that have missing arguments, have the wrong name for arguments, don't document thrown exceptions, etc.

I'm aware that there wouldn't be a perfect tool, since a tool can't tell us if the documentation is correct, but I'm hoping that identifying more obvious errors can at least help catch some incorrect JavaDoc comments.

Preferably this tool would have the means of ignoring simple getters and setters (I often don't include a `@returns` on getters, for example, because their summary details everything you'd need to know).

Comment: Tool agnostic. Eclipse works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Eclipse it's possible to mark missing or wrong JavaDoc.
Look at Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->JavaDoc. Activate Process JavaDoc comments and select the wanted options.

Comment: This works well. It doesn't seem to be able to ignore simple getters and setters, though.